# How to login to Onenote Store app automatically with O365 account?

Tags: windows-store-apps, ms-office, onenote, onenote-api

Let's say I have Access token for accessing OnenoteAPI. Now I want to launch notebook(access token is available) in onenote store client. If I launch for the first time Onenote Store app asks for login. Is it possible to autologin account in OnenoteStore and launch Notebook without asking for login Credentials?

Answer (score 0):

A OneNote API access token will not let you log into the OneNote store app automatically. You will have to log in there.